# magento soap catalogInventoryStockItemList by custom product attribute

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am trying to retrieve the stock amount of a product by a product custom attribute. Currently I can retrieve the stock amount by using the product ID instead of the costum attribute by using

```
$result = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList($sessionId, array('108906', '2'));
var_dump($result);
```

But how do I retrieve this by a costum attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You may start with this. To be able to achieve including `Custom Attribute`, you would want to override the below files:

*app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/wsdl.xml*

Override this as - *app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/wsdl.xml* to include your custom attribute:

**Line no: 56**

```
<message name="catalogInventoryStockItemListRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="products" type="typens:ArrayOfString" />
    <part name="customAttribute" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
```

*app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/wsi.xml*

Override this as - *app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/wsi.xml* to include your custom attribute:

**Line no: 55**

```
        <xsd:element name="catalogInventoryStockItemListRequestParam">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="productIds" type="typens:ArrayOfString" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="customAttribute" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

Then you can try your code as below:

```
$result = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList($sessionId, array('108906', '2'), 'custom_attribute_code');
var_dump($result);
```

I have NOT tried this in my machine. However, this can be a start for you.

Happy Coding...